# Differential of exponential function of $M_n(\mathbb(K))$

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, differential

I am trying to understand the proof for the following claim.

If $A,X\in M_n(K)$ such that $AX=XA$, then $d_Aexp(X)=exp(A)X$.

Proof: Consider the polynomial function $$P_k:M_n(K)\to M_n(K)\\ A\mapsto A^k$$If $AX=AX$, then
$$(A+tX)^k=\sum_{j=0}^{k}{ k\choose k -j}A^{k-j}(tX)^j=\sum_{j=0}^{k}{ k\choose k -j}t^jA^{k-j}X^j$$
(This is the part I don't get) Therefore, $$d_AP(X)=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{\substack{t=0}}(A+tX)^k=kA^{k-1}X$$.

Then the differential is obtained by differentiating the terms individually in the exponential series.

I don't understand both the equalities in the last equation. Any ideas?

Comment: What is $d_A$? Is it the directional derivative of the function $\exp(X)$ in the direction $A$? Anyway, this is about interchanging the derivative and the sum.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Based off the equations, I think they mean the other way. $A$ is the point where $\exp$ is evaluated and $X$ is the tangent vector.

Anyway, @N Singh, when you differentiate a polynomial in $t$ at $t=0$ you get the coefficient of $t$, which is exactly $kA^{k-1}X$ in this case. As for why that's $dP_A(X)$ (this is the more common notation), that's just chain rule. If $\gamma(t) = A+tX$,
$$(P\circ\gamma)'(0) = dP_{\gamma(0)}(\gamma'(0)) = dP_A(X).$$

Comment: @Glare Thank you for the clarification.